# How do I use an iterator twice inside of the quote! macro?

Tags: rust, quote

I'm trying to implement the builder pattern from the [proc macro workshop](https://github.com/dtolnay/proc-macro-workshop) I'm creating a proc macro which parses a struct, extracts its `name`, `field_names` and `field_types`. It should reproduce the struct itself and also create a builder struct with the same `field_names` but with *optional* types.

My problem is that `field_name` and `field_type` are iterators that I would have to use twice in order to create two structs out of one.

This is my source tree

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── builder-derive
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── lib.rs
└── src
    └── main.rs
```

`./cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "proc-macro-question"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["ropottnik <ropottnik@example.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
builder-derive = { path = "./builder-derive" }
```

`./main.rs`

```rust
#[derive(Builder)]
struct SomeStruct {
    some_field: i32,
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

`./builder-derive/cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "builder-derive"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["ropottnik <ropottnik@example.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
proc-macro = true

[dev-dependencies]
trybuild = { version = "1.0", features = ["diff"] }

[dependencies]
syn = { version= "1.0", features = ["extra-traits"] }
quote = "1.0"
```

`./builder-derive/src/lib.rs`

```rust
#[proc_macro_derive(Builder)]
pub fn derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input = parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput);
    let name = &input.ident;
    let builder_name = format_ident!("{}Builder", &name);
    let fields = match &input.data {
        Data::Struct(DataStruct {
            fields: Fields::Named(fields),
            ..
        }) => &fields.named,
        _ => panic!("expected a struct with named fields"),
    };

    let field_name = fields.iter().map(|field| &field.ident);
    let field_type = fields.iter().map(|field| &field.ty);

    let expanded = quote! {
        pub struct #name {
            #(#field_name: #field_type,)*
        }

        pub struct #builder_name {
            #(#field_name: Option<#field_type>,)*
        }
    };

    expanded.into()
}
```

`$ cargo run` output

```
warning: unused import: `Ident`
 --> builder-derive/src/lib.rs:1:18
  |
1 | use proc_macro::{Ident, TokenStream};
  |                  ^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `field_name`
  --> builder-derive/src/lib.rs:22:20
   |
19 |       let field_name = fields.iter().map(|field| &field.ident);
   |           ---------- move occurs because `field_name` has type `Map<syn::punctuated::Iter<'_, syn::Field>, [closure@builder-derive/src/lib.rs:19:40: 19:60]>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
22 |       let expanded = quote! {
   |  ____________________^
23 | |         pub struct #name {
24 | |             #(#field_name: #field_type,)*
25 | |         }
...  |
29 | |         }
30 | |     };
   | |     ^
   | |     |
   | |_____`field_name` moved due to this method call
   |       value used here after move
   |
note: this function consumes the receiver `self` by taking ownership of it, which moves `field_name`
  --> /Users/simon/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/quote-1.0.8/src/runtime.rs:53:28
   |
53 |         fn quote_into_iter(self) -> (Self, HasIter) {
   |                            ^^^^
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `field_type`
  --> builder-derive/src/lib.rs:22:20
   |
20 |       let field_type = fields.iter().map(|field| &field.ty);
   |           ---------- move occurs because `field_type` has type `Map<syn::punctuated::Iter<'_, syn::Field>, [closure@builder-derive/src/lib.rs:20:40: 20:57]>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
21 |
22 |       let expanded = quote! {
   |  ____________________^
23 | |         pub struct #name {
24 | |             #(#field_name: #field_type,)*
25 | |         }
...  |
29 | |         }
30 | |     };
   | |     ^
   | |     |
   | |_____`field_type` moved due to this method call
   |       value used here after move
   |
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I guess I could create one iterator per usage but that seems impossibly dumb to me ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterators can only be used zero or one time, not multiple; that's standard Rust and doesn't involve the `quote!` macro:

```rust
fn example() {
    let nums = std::iter::empty::<i32>();
    for _ in nums {}
    for _ in nums {}
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `nums`
   --> src/lib.rs:4:14
    |
2   |     let nums = std::iter::empty::<i32>();
    |         ---- move occurs because `nums` has type `std::iter::Empty<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
3   |     for _ in nums {}
    |              ----
    |              |
    |              `nums` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
    |              help: consider borrowing to avoid moving into the for loop: `&nums`
4   |     for _ in nums {}
    |              ^^^^ value used here after move
    |
note: this function consumes the receiver `self` by taking ownership of it, which moves `nums`
```

Even if you took the iterators by mutable reference, iterating through it once would exhaust it, leaving no values for the second usage.

You will need to clone the iterator:

```rust
use quote::quote; // 1.0.8

fn example() {
    let nums = std::iter::empty::<i32>();
    let nums2 = nums.clone();

    quote! {
        #(#nums)*
        #(#nums2)*
    };
}
```

You can also collect the iterator into a `Vec` and iterate over it multiple times:

```rust
use quote::quote; // 1.0.8

fn example() {
    let nums = std::iter::empty();
    let nums: Vec<i32> = nums.collect();
    
    quote! {
        #(#nums)*
        #(#nums)*
    };
}
```